# Speed (countable / uncountable)

Tags: determiners, countable-nouns, countability

Based on dictionaries' definitions, the noun "[speed](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/speed_1)" sounds to be either countable or uncountable. So please let me know if in the sentence bellow using the determiner "a" sounds natural to you or what:

> - That rock is coming at us [at ***a*** great speed](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20a%20great%20speed%2Cat%20great%20speed&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20great%20speed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20great%20speed%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 2):

The 'a' here seems OK (maybe emphatic) but also redundant. At any time, the rock has a single speed. I think grammatically the structure of the sentence is different with and without the 'a', but the meaning is not substantially changed.